# Let $ \ f(x)=x^{3}+3x^{2}-10x \ $ so that $f(1)=-6$ and $f(2)=0$

Tags: derivatives

Let $ \ f(x)=x^{3}+3x^{2}-10x \ $ so that f(1)=-6 and f(2)=0 . By mean value theorem there exists a number y in the open interval (0,1) such that $ \ f'(1+y)=6 \ $ . Then the value of  y lies in the range $ \ \frac{1}{2} \leq y \leq  \frac{3}{4} \ $.  $$ $$ By mean value theorem , $ \ f(2)- f(1)= f'(1+y) (2-1) \\ or, f'(1+y)=6  \\ But \ how \ to \ show \ that \ y \in (1/2, 3/4). Any \ help \ is \  appreciating . $

Answer (score 0):

Just note that $f'(3/2) = 23/4 < 6$ and $f'(7/4) = 155/16 > 6$ and apply the intermediate-value theorem to $f'$.